Passing more than ref to a child component in reactjs?
I'm trying to pass more than one ref down to a child component. I tried to pass the refs as an object and it works.
import React from "react";

// Parent component
function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const btnRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button ref={btnRef}>click me</button>
      <ChildComponent ref={{ inputRef, btnRef }} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Child component
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  /**
   * console.log ref -> {inputRef: {…}, btnRef: {…}}
   */

  return (
    <>This is Child Component</>
  );
});

export default App;


If there is any better way to do this please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Passing multiple refs to a child component can be done using the approach you've mentioned, if you're looking for alternative approaches, one option is to pass refs individually as props to the child component
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button ref={btnRef}>click me</button>
      <ChildComponent inputRef={inputRef} btnRef={btnRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Child component
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef(({ inputRef, btnRef }, ref) => {
  /**
   * You can use inputRef and btnRef directly here
   */

  

